# can not read post data in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm trying to post data to App Engine in the following manner:

```
sendMessage = function(path, data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: path, 
        data: data, 
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        failure: function(errMsg) { 
            alert(errMsg);
        },
        success: function(result,status,xhr){
            alert(result);
        }
    });
};
sendMessage('/chatMessage', {"message": "aaaa"});
```

The receiving code:

```
class ChatMessage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        message = self.request.get("message", "fail")
        logging.error('RequestBody:' + str(self.request.body))
        logging.error('Message:' + message)
```

The log messages:

```
ERROR    2013-05-18 16:23:31,954 channels.py:52] RequestBody:message=aaaa
ERROR    2013-05-18 16:23:31,956 channels.py:53] Message:fail
INFO     2013-05-18 18:23:31,983 server.py:585] default: "POST /chatMessage HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

Obviously the message got on the server intact since it says `message=aaaa` But why can't I "get" the message from the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you issue a POST request, you can either encode data into the URL, or put the data in the body of the request.

`request.get()` will get urlencoded parameters in the url.

In your case, you are putting the data in the body of the request, so everything is working properly.  If you want the data, you should parse it from the request body.